# How to create datalist dynamically

Tags: asp.net, datalist

In my application I want to create a dynamic datalist and bind the database values. please help me
this is my code

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataList datlst = new DataList();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select emname from emp", con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "emp");
    datlst.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    datlst.DataBind();
    //this.Controls.Add(datlst);
    form1.Controls.Add(datlst);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the codeBehind file write

```
DtaList dl = new DataList();
dl.DataSource = //Data from DB 
dl.DataBind();
```

Comment: Other things to bear in mind:

1. Set the DataList's ID property e.g dl.ID = "myDataList";
2. Add the DataList to the page/control e.g. using this.Controls.Add(dl);
3. Bind the DataList in a test for IsPostback if the query is not dynamic.

Comment: thank u for response but it is not getting please recheck once i send total code checkout thank u

Comment: mr.msi r u there please help about dynamic datalist