# dynamic controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

in my application i want to create dynamic datalist i created but it is not displaying
this is my code help me please, thank u.

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    DataList datlst = new DataList();
    datlst.ID = "mydatalist";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select emname from emp", con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "emp");

    datlst.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    datlst.DataBind();

    //this.Controls.Add(datlst);
   form1.Controls.Add(datlst);



}
```

Comment: Dublicate by the same user : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465053/how-to-create-datalist-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set Itemtemplate for the datalist where the data will be bound.
Please review this [**link**](http://aspalliance.com/1558_Dynamic_GridView_and_DataList_in_ASPNET_20.all) to create itemtemplate from code behind

Please check if it can help.

Comment: how to set the itemtemplate for please help me Himadri r u indian?

Comment: Yes. I m an Indian. Have you followed the link I have mentioned? Everything is implemented there. You can find how to create ItemTemplate, HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate. The Templates are defined in MyTemplate class which implements ITemplate
interface. Listing 4 contains how to create dynamic datalist and Set the ItemTemplate, HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate. Plz check